# What are the odds of A winning 2 games given that the odds of A winning a game is 3:2

Tags: probability

The odds in favor of A winning a game of chess against B are 3:2. If 3 games are to be played, what are the odds: 
(a) in favor of A winning at least 2 games out of 3,
(b) against A losing the first 2 games to B

It is known that the answer are:

(a) 81:44

(b) 21:4

I know this sentence ***The odds in favor of A winning a game of chess against B are 3:2.*** means:  out of 5 games, A will ideally win 3 times and lose 2 times. In other words,the probability of A to win a game is 3/(3+2) = 3/5 but I do not understand how the answers (a) and (b) were calculated.

Comment: I think it's always easier to work with probabilities.  As you say, $A$ wins with probability $\frac 35$.  So, now you just have a standard question about the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dislike working with odds as a matter of principle, so all my calculations will be in terms of probability.  We can rephrase things in terms of odds at the end.

We try then to calculate the *probability* that $A$ wins at least $2$ games out of $3$ as well as the *probability* that $A$ loses the first $2$ games against $B$.

As you correctly noted, if the odds in favor of $A$ winning against $B$ is $3:2$ that implies that the probability that $A$ wins a game is $\frac{3}{3+2}=\frac{3}{5}$.

To win *at least* two games out of three is equivalent to winning *exactly* two games or winning *exactly* three games out of three.  The probabilities for these to occur can be found via the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

The probability then of winning at least two games is $\binom{3}{2}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^2\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^1 + \binom{3}{3}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^3 = \dfrac{3\cdot 3^2\cdot 2 + 3^3}{5^3} = \frac{81}{125}$

The *odds* then are $81:(125-81)$ or rather $81:44$.

The second part of the problem is similarly calculated.

Answer (score 1):

In a.) part, you get the probability as $\frac{81}{125}$. Therefore, in the long run, out of $125$ games, $A$ will win $81$ games and lose $44$ games. Therefore the odds in favor of A are $81:44$.

Similarly calculate for part b